# Getting "The best overloaded method match for double.Parse(string) has some invalid arguments" error

Tags: c#

With this kind of code

```
double socialSecurityFee = 0;
double xsocialSecurityFee = double.Parse (socialSecurityFee);
```

I get this kind of error

> Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   `double.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502)
>   (socialSecurityFee)

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double.Parse` expects `string` as a parameter and you're trying to call it with another `double` value.

I'm not really sure why you're using `double.Parse` here, but to make it work add `ToString()` call:

```
double socialSecurityFee = 0;
double xsocialSecurityFee = double.Parse(socialSecurityFee.ToString());
```

or just assign the value itself (because it's already a `double`, isn't it?):

```
double socialSecurityFee = 0;
double xsocialSecurityFee = socialSecurityFee ;
```

Answer (score 4):

> What's wrong with my code?

Exactly what the compiler is telling you - none of the overloads of `double.Parse` is appropriate for a single argument of type `double`. It's not even clear what you'd mean by that - parsing is usually about converting from one type (commonly a string) into another type (`double` in this case). Your initial value is *already* a `double`, so what would you expect it to do?

My guess is that you actually have a string somewhere, and you're trying to parse that - so you need to change your argument so that it uses that string instead of the `socialSecurityFee` variable. It's not clear that you need two variables of type `double` at all.

In addition, if this is meant to represent a currency amount (as it sounds like) you should consider using `decimal` instead of `double`.

Comment: string socialSecurityFee = 0; double xsocialSecurityFee = double.Parse (socialSecurityFee);  if I change it that way, I get another error  :  Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `double' expression to type `string' (CS1503)

Comment: @user2536652: Well now you've changed the type of the variable, but you're trying to assign the value `0` to a string, which doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

There are four overloads of `Double.Parse`. Only one of them accepts a single parameter. The type of that parameter is a `string` but you are trying to pass a `double`. That is *exactly* what the compiler error message is telling you. You can not do that because `double`s are not implicitly convertible to `string`. You can't invoke a method using parameters that don't implicitly convert to the types the method expects.

But what are you trying to do? `socialSecurityFee` is a `double`, so why are you trying to *parse* it? Parsing means analyzing a `string` to give it meaning.

Comment: I didn't expect so many responses in so small amount of time. Now it works fine, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

The method `double.Parse()` expects a `string` argument, and you're passing it a `double` value.

Since your original value is already a double, you don't even need to use `double.Parse()`

Answer (score 0):

`socialSecurityFee` is already a double. `double.Parse` expects a string, tough. You don't need to parse anything here. What are you trying to do?